# Is this Avengers: Endgame character's fate really irreversible?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-endgame

In *Avengers: Endgame*

> Black Widow sacrifices her life so Barton can get the Soul Stone.

Later, when Hulk

> uses the Infinity Stones to bring back all the dead, he mentions that he couldn't bring back Black Widow.

I cannot recall any more dialogue in the film related to

> bringing Black Widow back

but I've seen multiple mentions online about how the movie confirmed it is impossible to do so. So did I miss some detail? Is it indeed impossible for

> Black Widow to have been resurrected or was it just Hulk who couldn't do it?

Comment: Go back in time and bring her back to the present just like Gamora. Done.

Comment: umm... lets wait till they introduce the one above all or the living tribunal

Answer (score 14):

## Yes

The Russo brothers actually answered this in an interview from [this Chinese source](https://ent.qq.com/a/20190429/007983.htm). As the original article is in Chinese I am getting the quotes from [this reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/marvelstudios/comments/bj0it4/joe_russos_qa_about_the_plot_of_avengers_endgame/), although I think all that's happened is that the user ran it through Google Translate.

> Q: Can you get the soul your sacrificed for the Soul Stone back when you return it?
>
> A: No, the process is irreversible. Even if you have returned it to its original location, you wouldn't be able to get the person back. In fact, it's not really returning the stone, more like put it back properly. The tribute soul for the soul stone will forever be sealed in that place, therefore Black Widow is gone forever.

---

It is apparently impossible, according to Red Skull and the Hulk. I can’t remember Red Skull’s exact quote from *Endgame* but he says something similar in *Infinity War*.

> **Red Skull:** To ensure that whoever possesses it... Understands its power... The stone demands a sacrifice.
>
> **Thanos:** Of what?
>
> **Red Skull:** In order to take the stone you must lose that which you love. A soul...For a soul.
>
> <sub>*Avengers: Infinity War*</sub>

As in you can’t return the sacrifice because they have been traded for the Soul Stone. This makes sense when we see Hulk try and bring her back and he can’t even though he has control over all the Infinity Stones.

> What is interesting though is that Cap took the Soul Stone back from where it was taken so presumably if it was placed back Nat could come back I.e. giving up the Soul Stone to have her back. That is just speculation though.

Comment: Probably not, since obtaining the stone requires a *sacrifice*, not a safety deposit to be reclaimed once you're done using it.

Comment: @Shadur yeah that’s just complete speculation on my part, the main part of my answer is before that

Comment: I would pay to see Cap face when he return back the sool stone and find out that Red Skull is it's gardien

Answer (score 8):

I'm of the opinion that it's impossible right up until

> Disney/Marvel realizes there's more money to be made by bringing her back.

That said, in-movie the evidence we have is what you said in your question, plus

> Clint / Hawkeye/Ronin stated that Red Skull told him it's impossible as well.

That said, one could argue

> Gamora returning demonstrates one possible loophole.

Comment: Gamora never returned that was her past self, you are mistaken here.

Comment: So that means that they can go back in time to a few days before she died, and bring that version of her forward into the future.  There's no way to limit the Gamora loophole to just Gamora.

Comment: They already realized your first spoiler. There is a Black Widow movie in the work, granted it is a prequel.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot, I'm talking about how to bring the character back into the movie from the audience perspective, I recognize that's not the same as resurrection in universe

Comment: That also means that "past-Starlord" has no Gamora, because she is now in the present.

Comment: Of course. we all've seen how characters resurrects from impossible deaths once and another in the comics... so why would be different on the big screen?

Comment: @Bardo - The thing is, Coulson aside, it *was* different in the MCU, until now.

Comment: @Adamant that's because until now, there have been just few deaths on MCU, and none of key characters.