# Can the Soul Stone be acquired by 'sacrificing' Wade Wilson?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, deadpool, infinity-stones

As we all know, the acquisition of the Soul Stone requires a sacrifice. Is it by any way possible to acquire it by 'sacrificing' dear old Deadpool?

Something like this:

[image: Comic showing Spider-Man and Deadpool going to get the Soul Stone from Vormir. Deadpool sacrifices himself and so Spider-Man gets the Stone from Red skull, Deadpool then comes back to life asking if he got the Stone and Red Skull says: "Am I a joke to you?"]:

Comment: I downvoted because I think the question is unanswerable with respect to Deadpool, and I am not sure why one of the many regenerating characters from the MCU was not chosen as an example.

Comment: Oh! Well I guess you're right. I mean I definitely could have chosen hulk. No hard feelings BTW :)

Comment: @d4rk4ng31 There's no indication that the Hulk can't die in the MCU...

Comment: @AnthonyGrist - Hulk certainly has strong regenerative powers in the MCU. Whether Deadpool (or  Wolverine or....) "can't die" depends on the writer of the comic (cough...the Punisher kills Wolverine with electrified wire...cough).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The process of [sacrificing someone for the Soul Stone is irreversible](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/210971/58193) so it would seem that sacrificing someone with regenerative abilities would not help you keep the person.

> Q: Can you get the soul your sacrificed for the Soul Stone back when you return it?
>
> A: No, the process is irreversible. Even if you have returned it to its original location, you wouldn't be able to get the person back. In fact, it's not really returning the stone, more like put it back properly. The tribute soul for the soul stone will forever be sealed in that place, therefore Black Widow is gone forever.

There's no character in the MCU with powers quite like Deadpool's. Sure some have regenerative abilities but none have them to the same level as Wade. The closest we have is probably the Hulk. For a close situation we have Smart Hulk's reverse Snap in *Avengers: Endgame* and the [permanent damage](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/212097/58193) to his arm because of it.

> “He’s lost an arm,” Russo says. “He lost Natasha. That’s not coming back. He’s damaged himself. I don’t know. It’s interesting. That’s permanent damage, the same way that it was permanent damage with Thanos. It’s irreversible damage. His arm, if you noticed, is a lot skinnier. It’s blackened. So, he loses a lot of strength there.”
>
> Russo does acknowledge that “permanent” means something different a world of magic and super science, but that’s not his concern any longer.
>
> “But who knows? There’s a lot of smart people left,” he says. “Maybe someone helps him repair that. Maybe someone gives him a new arm. I have no idea where that character goes from here. The nice thing is we didn’t have to pay attention to where it goes after this, we just try to tell a satisfying ending.”
>
> <sub>[Comicbook, Avengers: Endgame Director Reveals Hulk's Injury Is Permanent](https://comicbook.com/marvel/2019/05/07/avengers-endgame-hulk-injury-permanent-infinity-stones-joe-russo/)</sub>

Lastly, of course Wade Wilson, aka Deadpool, currently resides in the X-Men Cinematic Universe and not the Marvel Cinematic Universe. As we haven't seen Deadpool in the MCU yet we can't answer the question as to whether a Soul Stone sacrifice would work for him but we can say that currently the answer is no, yes, neither or both as he does not yet exist in the MCU; it's a real Schrödinger's Deadpool situation.

Comment: But doesn't the soul stone exist in the X-men Cinematic Universe too?

Comment: @d4rk4ng31 As far as I'm aware none of the Infinity Stones have been shown to exist in the XCU but I may be wrong on that.

Comment: XCU has 7 infinity stones

Comment: @d4rk4ng31 Got a source for that? I've done a quick search and can't find any confirmation of that.

Comment: [This](https://www.marvel.com/items/ego-gem) link is for the ego-gem. Still searching for XCU

Comment: @d4rk4ng31 there has been zero* crossover between MCU and XCU plots, characters (a special exception for Quicksilver), races, objects (excepting the unmentioned SHIELD helicarrier in Deadpool) and locations. There are no Infinity Stones/Gems in the XCU.

Answer (score 1):

I doubt it. First, obviously the question of whether it can be acquired by sacrificing Wade Wilson is about as answerable as asking whether sacrificing Edward Cullen would suffice. Neither of them exists in the Marvel Cinematic Universe.

However, the closely related question of whether someone with powers *like* Deadpool would work is answerable. Deadpool regenerates from what would otherwise be fatal injuries. There are many characters in the MCU with similar powers, although these traits are frequently overshadowed by their other abilities. However, most obviously, Asgardians (like Thor) and the Hulk can both regenerate from seemingly lethal injuries.<sup>1</sup> Possibly Captain Marvel as well. We also should not forget S.H.I.E.L.D.'s Project T.A.H.I.T.I., which can resurrect even a dead human being, if applied quickly enough.

So the Avengers literally have people who can regenerate from fatal injuries among their numbers, not to mention (if they can access S.H.I.E.L.D's secret files) knowledge of a means of reviving a recently-dead human. If they had thought there was the slightest possibility that any of these people with regenerative abilities could acquire the Soul Stone without requiring an actual death, I imagine that they would have tried that first.

Therefore, I suspect there simply was not any means of cheating the system. No death, no Soul Stone.

<sub>1: Hulk: Banner says that he shot himself with a bullet, and that the Hulk spat it out. In addition, Banner jumps hundreds of feet onto the rainbow bridge, bouncing about three feet in the air, before lying unmoving. Then he transforms into the Hulk, with all injuries completely healed. Finally, he is bitten by Fenrir, whose fang penetrates his leg, but immediately afterward, no wound is visible. Thor: As an Asgardian, Thor has regenerative powers. In *Agents of S.H.I.E.L.D., an Asgardian berserker demonstrated the ability to survive a fatal injury, and Thor is much more powerful. His eye did not grow back, but seeing as it was put out by the Goddess of Death I think we can cut him some slack.</sub>

Comment: None of those characters have regenerative powers even close to Deadpool and none have been shown to regenerate from fatal injuries with _maybe_ the exception of Thor but that seems more because of Mjolnir than Thor's own powers. Also worth noting the Avengers didn't know about the details of the sacrifice so your speculative theory has a big hole in it. If they didn't know how it worked they're not going to think of ways to cheat the system.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot - The regeneration of Asgardians is covered pretty clearly in Agents of S.H.I.E.L.D. As for the Hulk, when Banner tried to shoot himself, the Hulk spit it out. Banner also jumped like a hundred feet onto a bridge, was unmoving, and then turned into the Hulk.

Comment: The thing is that when characters are also extremely hard to hurt, it's hard to see their regeneration at work, but it is still clearly there.

Comment: I've not watched AoS so can't comment on that but as far as I'm aware Asgardians do not have regenerative capabilities on the same level as Deadpool.

Comment: Does it really matter, though? The "Deadpool" question is unanswerable, but by the author's own admission they could have used Hulk as an illustration instead. The question of whether Bruce Banner can suffer a "fatal" injury and then revive by turning into the Hulk is very answerable.

Comment: Sure when talking about Bruce but then the question is, is he suffering a fatal injury or is the Other Guy simply stopping it by being stronger? In either case I've covered it in my answer now: it wouldn't have worked because: damage by snapping is irreversible (Hulk, Banner, Tony) and the exchange is everlasting for the Soul Stone: doesn't matter on regenerative abilities or not.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot - Bruce clearly fell and was seriously injured.  He bounced like three feet in the air, while in his Banner form, where we know he is just a regular human. If he was not dead after that fall, he was pretty close. *Then* he turned into the (unhurt) Hulk.

Comment: Then Fenris bites him. No evidence of any wound on the leg in subsequent shots. In *The Incredible Hulk*, Sterns says Bruce's blood can cure any disease.

Comment: In Ragnarok sure, I missed your comment edit and thought you were only talking about the suicide attempt.